# In the checkout page, how to default select and load a payment method?

Tags: payment, payment-methods, default

In the final magento checkout page, at the payment method part, I have two options, SagePay and PayPal.

Neither are selected, but I would like the SagePay option preselected by default, and therefore load automatically without the customer having to select anything.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Onepage Checkout you can edit `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Payment/Methods.php` -> `public function getSelectedMethodCode()` and to change:

```
return false;
```

with:

```
return parent::getSelectedMethodCode(); //if you like to select the first payment method
```

or:

```
return 'code_of_the_payment'; //the code of the payment that you like, I don't know what is for SagePay
```

It's recommended to create a module that rewrites this class or at least copy the file in `app/code/local` and edit the copy.

Comment: As much as I am not a fan of editing "Core" as it's not a good practice, but your solution does what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: How this can be achieved on Magento 2 for multiple countries??

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution  is goto methods.phtml at `app>design/frontent/yourpackage/your template/template/checkout/onepage/payment/`

AND find

```
<input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" checked="checked" class="radio" /></span>
        <?php $oneMethod = $_code; ?>
```

and here you need  put your logic.

```
<?php if($_code=='yourpayemntcode'): ?> checked="checked"   <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: How this can be achieved on Magento 2 for multiple countries??

Comment: This could cause problems if another payment method was already selected for the current checkout session/quote

Answer (score 1):

You can set sorting order for payment (and shipping) methods in the admin backend. Under Configuration > Payment Methods you can select each available method and set the sort order to a lower number.

Comment: Unfortunately not all payment methods have a sort order field. PayPal being the first that springs to mind.